# How to make multiple files using Powershell

Tags: powershell, shell, operating-system, window

How to change this command to make file name 001.js , 002.js , 003.js ...
instead of 1.js , 2.js , 3.js ... ?

```
1..100 | foreach {New-Item -path "C:\Users\suuii\Desktop\A\$_.js"
```

Comment: Try :  "C:\Users\suuii\Desktop\A" + $_.ToString("#000") + ".js"

Answer (score 0, accepted):

One alternative:

```
1..100 | % { "{0:d3}" -f $_ } | % { ni "C:\Users\suuii\Desktop\A$_.js" }
```

Another:

```
1..100 | % tostring 000 | % { ni "C:\Users\suuii\Desktop\A$_.js" }
```